# Queryset filtering using an array of GenericForeignKey objects

Tags: python, django, orm

Here's the problem.

I have a table that contains records which associate a user with an object that is defined by a GenericForeignKey

I can obtain a list of these objects as such:

```
association_objects = Association.objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

This will return an array of objects, and I can access the associated object with

```
association_object.context
```

So I can easily make an array of just the context objects

NOW I need to query ALL records of another table that are related to any of the objects in the aforementioned Association array.

In a good and holy universe, I could do something like

```
Action.objects.filter(context__in = associations)
```

where context in that table is ALSO a GenericForeignKey

However, GFK's cannot be filtered on their actual key property. You have to filter by both content type and primary key simultaneously...

How the hell do I do this? The only bright idea I had was seperate content_type and id into two separate arrays and do __in filters on both properties, but that doesn't seem like it would actually work.

Anyone got any bright ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I need it also!

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Action)
action_ids = association_objects.values_list("object_id", flat=True)\
                                .filter(content_type=ct)
actions = Action.objects.filter(pk__in=action_ids)
```

(assuming your `GenericForeignKey` consists of a `content_type` and `object_id`!)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
# I assume that association_objects is a QuerySet
association_ids = association_objects.value_list("id", flat=True)
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Association)
actions = Action.objects.filter(content_type=content_type,
                                object_id__in=association_ids)
```

Comment: but content_type can be variable if I understand correctly. The objects that are associated can be any model in the DB

Comment: Yes, content_type may refer to any model. But in your case you need to select only `Association`s right? PS. I've just corrected my answer (2nd line).

Comment: no, maybe I didn't phrase the question clearly enough (just thinking out loud). Associations are related to any object by GFK... and from GFK to Actions.... Think of Associations as a linker table between User and Actions. I need to use Associations as a bridge from the User to the Action based on whatever object context is necessary (any Model in the DB)

Comment: Could you update yout question and include the code for your models? Not everything, just the bits where you define the relationships.